# Is there a command in OpenSSL that allows me to compute Diffie-Hellman secrets?

Tags: openssl

For example, I already have g, a, b, p, but I want to compute g^a mod(p) and g^b mod(p), is there a command I can use in OpenSSL? I couldn't find one after looking for an hour.

Comment: If you're on a platform where openssl command is available, you'll likely be able to install python3 from your local package manager, and use its `pow` function like this: `pow(g, a, p)`

Comment: To me this question is about using software, not really about cryptography. I would move it to SO or to Security SE.

Comment: A=g^a mod p and B=g^b mod p are the _public_ keys, not secret, in DH. a and b are the _private keys_ and g^(ab) mod p is the shared/agreed secret. Given one of the public keys and one of the private keys, e.g. (p,g,a) and  (p,g,B), [openssl pkeyutl -derive`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkeyutl.html) computes the agreement and optionally applies certain KDFs to it.